# automatize port forwarding for remote jupyter notebook / lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I use a lot jupyter notebook on remote shared machines. I find very boring checking the allocated port, starting the ssh tunnel and opening the link.

I am wondering if there are tools that automatize that. I found https://github.com/Olllom/jump but it doesn't to be maintained and it is very bounded to conda. It should not be very difficult to implement, but I am wondering if other tools already exits.

Here some desidered feature:

- only one command to have the notebook open in your browser
- support for virtualenv / conda / ...
- support for initialization scripts
- automatic creation of virtual env on the remote
- automatic handling the ports (if already used...)
- automatic handling the remote hostname (e.g. if the remote is actually a pool of machine)
- managing multiple sessions (e.g. also killing them)